# Create a star shape of a specific size and rotation?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I want to make a star shape. I need to make it 32 x 32 pixels. Is there a way to define an explicit size with the tool? Right now I'm dragging with the mouse to create the shape, and hoping that it's about 32x32 and rotated evenly. This of course is not ideal!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Make your star shape
2. ctrl+T (free transform)
3. At the top, right click where it says 100% for either width or height, change
   to pixels.
   Now you can manually type in 32 pixels.

Comment: Cool that worked, but is there a way to define its rotation at creation time too? I think the star does not look symmetrical because when I create it, it's just being dragged and rotated randomly. I'm just eyeballing it so it looks somewhat upright. When you look close though, you can see it's not symmetrical.

Comment: Hi again... while creating the star hold shift. It won't rotate fully while you create it, I think it only rotates if you drag too far left and right (it can only rotate like 45 degrees at a time, so it's easy to lock it into a default rotation)